# SQL Case statement with subtraction and avoiding a negative value

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, case

I have a SQL stored procedure with a case statement. The statement is taking a cost and adding to it for the specific ExtCostCategory.

However, for WHSE-BRDR this needs to subtract 0.05 from the cost. How can I write this to avoid a negative value if PriceUOMCost is less than 0.05?

```
update t
set PriceUOMCost = cast(case c.ExtCostCategory  
                            when 'WHSE-VEND' then x.PriceUOMCost + 0.05
                            when 'WHSE-RETL' then x.PriceUomCost + 0.08
                            when 'WHSE-BRDR' then x.PriceUOMCost - 0.05
                            when 'VEND-BRDR' then x.PriceUOMCost + 0.05
                            else x.PriceUOMCost 
                        end as decimal(10,3))
```

Comment: What do you want to happen instead of a negative value?

Comment: `..then case when x.PriceUOMCost >0.05 then x.PriceUOMCost - 0.05 else 0 end ..`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know If I am missing something but can't you just do that?

```
when 'WHSE-BRDR' and x.PriceUOMCost >= 0.5 then x.PriceUOMCost - 0.05
```

Comment: Thanks, but this caused a syntax error.  I was able to use one of the suggested comments to add another case statement then (case 
              when x.PriceUOMCost > 0.05 then x.priceuomcost - 0.05
              else x.priceuomcost end)